# Messed up C: Permissions

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, permissions

I wanted to give a permission to a user, using SQL server. I think I did something wrong as now I can't access my Disk C.

I tried to reset permissions with Command prompt but it didn't allow me to do it. I also tried recovery and didn't allow me either..

There is important data on Disk C.. what should I do to regain access?

[image]

If I click on "Change", after 1 min. a warning message comes up saying: Windows Security >> Can`t open access control editor.  Access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Run as Administrator `cmd` and type:

Goto Root disk C:\ :

```
CD \
```

make the owner of the current user of file objects from the specified:

```
TAKEOWN /F C:\ /R /A /D Y
```

reset permissions for the file system by default:

```
icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET
```

set the initial file system permissions, registry for errors and GPOs for the workstation is not part of the domain by default:

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
```

Comment: You have not provided any explanation for your answer. What do these commands do? At present your answer is of limited value to readers who hope to understand how to resolve the issue.

Comment: @suspectus Unfortunately, there are two lines of conduct, or to trust, relying on my integrity, or spend a lot of experimentation with the teams in a virtual machine and become the owner of the knowledge based on personal experience. Then explanations do not mean anything, because theoretically they can be false and violate your security. Updated. This may be a response to be more attractive)